# Creating a paragraph in a cell that utilises words from different cells

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am looking to create a thank you message to a large set of data using Google Sheets.
I have names and the message, and I wonder if there is a quicker way to create the message for all, rather than typing each.

For example

```
A1            B1
Beth          Hi (name in A1), thank you so much for joining us...
```

I tried different custom formula, but could not make it work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you just need to concatenate operator. Try-

```
="Hi " & A1 & ", thank you so much for joining us..."
```

[image]